# \beamersize options

Tags: beamer, size

I am writing my own beamer theme and run into trouble to define and access size properties.

First of all, I have found these properties:

```
\setbeamersize{
    text margin left    = .04\paperwidth,
    text margin right   = .04\paperwidth,
    sidebar width left  = 0mm,
    sidebar width right = 10mm,
    description width   = 10mm,
    mini frame size     = 10mm,
    mini frame offset   = 10mm
}
```

Are there more? I need on to define the size of the header.

Second:
How can I access one of these variables? let's say I want to draw something in my sidebar:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{sidebar right}{mytheme}
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox[](0,0) rectangle(10mm,\paperheight);
        \usebeamercolor{palette primary};
        \fill[left color=red, right color=bg!40!black] (0,0) rectangle (10mm,\paperheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

How can I set the manual defined 10mm to the variable sidebar width left?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In addition the the listed ones the option `description width of=⟨text⟩` is available, it "sets the default width of description labels to the width of the ⟨text⟩, see Section 12.1." of the beamer user guide
2. to change the height of the headline, you can use `\setlength{\beamer@headheight}{4cm}`
3. The width of the sidebar is stored in `\beamer@sidebarwidth`.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[width=10mm]{Berkeley}

\usepackage{tikz}


\makeatletter
\setlength{\beamer@headheight}{4cm}

\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox[](0,0) rectangle(\beamer@sidebarwidth,\paperheight);
        \usebeamercolor{palette primary};
        \fill[left color=red, right color=bg!40!black] (0,0) rectangle (10mm,\paperheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```